# pass post data with window.location.href

Tags: javascript, jquery

When using window.location.href, I'd like to pass POST data to the new page I'm opening.  is this possible using JavaScript and jQuery?

Comment: Setting `window.location.href` does a GET request for the new URL, not POST.

Answer (score 89):

Using `window.location.href` it's not possible to send a POST request.

What you have to do is to set up a `form` tag with data fields in it, set the `action` attribute of the form to the URL and the `method` attribute to POST, then call the `submit` method on the `form` tag.

Comment: I have data coming from 3 different forms and I am trying to send all 3 forms to the same page so I've been trying to serialize the forms with jQuery and send them some other way

Comment: @Brian: Can't you just put everything in one `form`, so everything is sent together automatically?

Comment: One form is in a jQueryUI dialog box - so I can't just include them all.

Comment: Pull out all their values, _dynamically_ build a form with all of the fields in all three forms, and submit that form.  The form can be invisible.  Don't use a JQuery AJAX method, use `$("#myForm").submit()`.  The form- which will be invisible, and only used to submit values from your client side code, not user input- will never be shown nor otherwise used, and the page will be refreshed.

Answer (score 89):

Add a form to your HTML, something like this:

```
<form style="display: none" action="/the/url" method="POST" id="form">
  <input type="hidden" id="var1" name="var1" value=""/>
  <input type="hidden" id="var2" name="var2" value=""/>
</form>
```

and use JQuery to fill these values (of course you can also use javascript to do something similar)

```
$("#var1").val(value1);
$("#var2").val(value2);
```

Then finally submit the form

```
$("#form").submit();
```

on the server side you should be able to get the data you sent by checking `var1` and `var2`, how to do this depends on what server-side language you are using.

Comment: when i do this, I get my browser to redirect to domain/undefined. What  am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 28):

As it was said in other answers there is no way to make a POST request using window.location.href, to do it you can create a form and submit it immediately.

You can use this function:

```
function postForm(path, params, method) {
    method = method || 'post';

    var form = document.createElement('form');
    form.setAttribute('method', method);
    form.setAttribute('action', path);

    for (var key in params) {
        if (params.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            var hiddenField = document.createElement('input');
            hiddenField.setAttribute('type', 'hidden');
            hiddenField.setAttribute('name', key);
            hiddenField.setAttribute('value', params[key]);

            form.appendChild(hiddenField);
        }
    }

    document.body.appendChild(form);
    form.submit();
}

postForm('mysite.com/form', {arg1: 'value1', arg2: 'value2'});
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/133997/2965158

Comment: Great answer, thank you. But I found a problem with repeated values which are sometimes needed like `id=2&id=5`. I have modified your code so that I check if params[key].constructor !== Array. If so, I convert such non-array values to array (with single element), now all keys have an array value and I cycle through such arrays. This allows me to have repeated values in the parameter (in such case I enter them as an array) and inside the form.

Comment: @mirek can you post the code here

Answer (score 11):

Use this file : "jquery.redirect.js"

```
$("#btn_id").click(function(){
    $.redirect(http://localhost/test/test1.php,
        {
            user_name: "khan",
            city : "Meerut",
            country : "country"
        });
    });
});
```

see https://github.com/mgalante/jquery.redirect

Answer (score 9):

Short answer: no. `window.location.href` is not capable of passing POST data.

Somewhat more satisfying answer: You can use this function to clone all your form data and submit it.

```
var submitMe = document.createElement("form");
submitMe.action = "YOUR_URL_HERE"; // Remember to change me
submitMe.method = "post";
submitMe.enctype = "multipart/form-data";
var nameJoiner = "_";
// ^ The string used to join form name and input name
//   so that you can differentiate between forms when
//   processing the data server-side.
submitMe.importFields = function(form){
    for(k in form.elements){
        if(input = form.elements[k]){
            if(input.type!="submit"&&
                     (input.nodeName=="INPUT"
                    ||input.nodeName=="TEXTAREA"
                    ||input.nodeName=="BUTTON"
                    ||input.nodeName=="SELECT")
                     ){
                var output = input.cloneNode(true);
                output.name = form.name + nameJoiner + input.name;
                this.appendChild(output);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

- Do `submitMe.importFields(form_element);` for each of the three forms you want to submit.
- This function will add each form's name to the names of its child inputs (If you have an `<input name="email">` in `<form name="login">`, the submitted name will be `login_name`.
- You can change the `nameJoiner` variable to something other than `_` so it doesn't conflict with your input naming scheme.
- Once you've imported all the necessary forms, do `submitMe.submit();`

Answer (score 6):

Have you considered simply using Local/Session Storage? -or- Depending on the complexity of what you're building; you could even use indexDB.

***note*:**

`Local storage` and `indexDB` are not secure - so you want to avoid storing any sensitive / personal data (i.e names, addresses, emails addresses, DOB etc) in either of these.

`Session Storage` is a more secure option for anything sensitive, it's only accessible to the origin that set the items and also clears as soon as the browser / tab is closed.

`IndexDB` is a little more [but not much more] complicated and is a `30MB noSQL database` built into every browser (but can be basically unlimited if the user opts in) -> next time you're using Google docs, open you DevTools -> application -> IndexDB and take a peak. [spoiler alert: it's encrypted].

Focusing on `Local` and `Session Storage`; these are both dead simple to use:

```
// To Set 
sessionStorage.setItem( 'key' , 'value' );

// e.g.
sessionStorage.setItem( 'formData' , { name: "Mr Manager", company: "Bluth's Frozen Bananas", ...  } );    

// Get The Data 
const fromData = sessionStorage.getItem( 'key' );     

// e.g. (after navigating to next location)
const fromData = sessionStorage.getItem( 'formData' );

// Remove 
sessionStorage.removeItem( 'key' );

// Remove _all_ saved data sessionStorage
sessionStorage.clear( );
```

If simple is not your thing -or- maybe you want to *go off road* and try a different approach all together -> you can probably use a `shared web worker`... y'know, just for kicks.

Answer (score 4):

it's as simple as this

```
$.post({url: "som_page.php", 
    data: { data1: value1, data2: value2 }
    ).done(function( data ) { 
        $( "body" ).html(data);
    });
});
```

I had to solve this to make a screen lock of my application where I had to pass sensitive data as user and the url where he was working. Then create a function that executes this code

Comment: Or in the `done()` function set `window.location.href`

Comment: Yes @ChrisEdwards, in my example i try to use te return data from jquery post. I hope that it would be useful to someone.

Answer (score 2):

I use a very different approach to this.  I set browser cookies in the client that expire a second after I set `window.location.href`.

This is way more secure than embedding your parameters in the URL.

The server receives the parameters as cookies, and the browser deletes the cookies right after they are sent.

```js
const expires = new Date(Date.now() + 1000).toUTCString()
document.cookie = `oauth-username=user123; expires=${expires}`
window.location.href = `https:foo.com/oauth/google/link`
```

Comment: there's limit how many cookies you can store and also multiple concurrent requests 
 will be issue

Answer (score -4):

You can use GET instead of pass, but don't use this method for important values,

```
function passIDto(IDval){    
window.location.href = "CustomerBasket.php?oridd=" +  IDval ;
}
```

In the CustomerBasket.php

```
<?php
  $value = $_GET["oridd"];
  echo  $value;
?>
```

Comment: its GET method but question is POST method buddy

Comment: @thamaraiselvam Kissa Mia may not have phrased the answer well but is right about the GET route here. The question is not hardwired to using the POST method - the user just asked if there was a way to take *POST data* and send it via window.location.href. And you should first know that Window.location.href **IS** a GET request. This answer is not wrong - it simply won't be easy to scale to a large number of form fields, encoded as a QueryString. However, the most obvious way of sending data via a URL (which is what you can change with window.location.href) is via query string parameters.

Comment: @SylonZero You can't attach POST data to a GET request.  They are different kinds of requests and the data looks different in a POST.  The important parts of the HTTP spec are fairly short.

Comment: @ColinvH You need to read what I've written more carefully. TLDR version: you can take the data that would be used to generate a POST and encode it as query string params.