# jquery/js - i have a bunch of values (strings). i want to send it to another url via POST, how do i do this?

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have this (simplified)

```
<script>

  dataToSend = 'dummy data here';

function sendIt() {

//code here

}
</script>

<a href='#' onclick='sendIt();'>Click here to send data</a>
```

what would i need to put in sendIt() to do a POST submit (not ajax, i want the user to be sent to the page too).

using jquery

Comment: No need of jquery to do that... <a href="yourpage.php?dataToSend='dummy data here'">Click to send data</a>
or in POST : <form action="yourpage.php" method="post"><input name="dataToSend" type="text" value="dummy data here"/><input type="submit" value="Send data"/></form>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what you would want to with this but here you go

```
<script type="text/javascript">
dataToSend = 'dummy data here';
function sendIt() {
        $('body').append('<form id="sendit" method="post"><input type="hidden" name="data" value="'+dataToSend+'"/></form>');
        $('#sendit').submit();
}
</script>

<a href='#' onclick='sendIt();'>Click here to send data</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a work around. Why not create a form and a hidden text field that contains the string, and trigger the form submit when the link is clicked.

```
<form id="fauxForm" method="POST">
  <input type="hidden" value="dummy data here" />
</form>
<a id="sendData" href="submithere.php">Click here to send data</a>

<script type="text/javascript">
  $("#sendData").click(function(ev){
    ev.preventDefault();
    $("#fauxForm").attr("action",$(this).attr("href")).submit();
  });
</script>
```

Comment: <input type="submit" value="Send data"/> do the work, no need of javascript for that lol

Comment: He wanted to do it via a link for whatever reason.

Comment: Why do things simply when we can complicate them... ;-)

Comment: i simplified my example a lot. it won't be sent when user clicks something, but sent via a function. i could do a hidden form but it seems a bit overkill?

Answer (score 0):

The easy way is to add a form. You do not need javascript.

```
<form action=" .. url.." method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="dataToSend" value="dummy data here">
    <input name="sendIt" id="sendIt" type="submit" value="Click here to send data">
</form>
```

Answer (score -1):

Short answer is it isn't possible to send a post from JavaScript alone.  Longer answer is available from [pass post data with window.location.href](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2367979/pass-post-data-with-window-location-href)  On the other hand, you can turn it into a GET request (e.g. http://www.misyte.com/page?param=value&param=value&etc=data) and get the data to the page that way.

Comment: absolutely it is.  XmlHttpRequest can do just that.  it's native JavaScript and can even be synchronous.

Comment: XmlHttpRequest doesn't also send the user to said page.