# Hide querystring in javascriptPost Method

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax

I have following javascript :

```
  var link = AjaxLocation + "/createDataSet.aspx";
    $j.post(link, null, function() {
        window.location.replace("/admin/SavedDataSet_edit.aspx?businessId="+data);
    }, "html");
```

`createDataSet.aspx` page returns businessId for `SavedDataSet_edit.aspx` page...

whenever page redirect to `SavedDataSet_edit.aspx` page, querystring displays in the addressbar of the browser.

how to hide Querystring ?? and if i hide querystring from the browser then how to fetch it in the `SavedDataSet_edit.aspx` page??

Thanks..

Comment: Why are you doing a `POST` with a query string? Why not just set the `data` of the request?

Comment: The OP is not doing a `POST` with a query string, the `window.location.replace` is a `GET` that is the callback of the `POST` to `createDataSet.aspx`.

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of ways to achive that: you can use cookies(I wouldn't recommend) you can post to our page hidden field and then retrieve it using FormCollection property of the Request object. To post to your page you would need to craete dynamically a form that then submit it, the code would look like:

```
var link = AjaxLocation + "/createDataSet.aspx";
    $j.post(link, null, function() {

        $("<form action='/admin/SavedDataSet_edit.aspx'><input name='businessId' type='hidden' value='"+ data +"'></form>").appendTo('body').submit();


    }, "html");
```

Answer (score 0):

The only way to hide it is to pass it to SavedDataSet_edit.aspx, store it in session, then have that page redirect to itself without the querystring.  Or use a different page in-between the two to save in session.  Or, you  could encrypt the value and pass encrypted querystring, provided data is a value coming from the server.

Make sure, even though you may do that, to check permissions on the resource to see that the user is authorized.

Answer (score 0):

`window.location.replace` is not a POST request, so it cannot send POST data. So your choices are:

1. Keep using the query string route and just live with the value showing, sounds like this is not a realistic option though
2. Put the query string data into a form and submit the form as described in various answers to [pass post data with window.location.href](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2367979/pass-post-data-with-window-location-href).
3. Leverage the AJAX call you are already making to `createDataSet.aspx` and store the value you want to retrieve on `SavedDataSet_edit.aspx` page by storing the `businessId` data in `Session` when you are in the `createDataSet.aspx` and then retrieving it from `Session` cache when you are in the `Page_Load` of `SaveDataSet_edit.aspx`.