# how to redirect a page in javascript with passing values to another page

Tags: javascript

```
window.location="http://test.rgniyd.com/test1/?q=node/36/"&dept="+ dept +"&bath="+  
bat +"&month=+month+"&year="+year+"&semester="+sem";
```

how to redirect the page to http://test.rgniyd.com/test1/?q=node/36/  with values in
JavaScript. the above code is not working , please help or please suggest me how to     redirect page without clearing the session values in JavaScript

Comment: your &s should be inside the string. Remove the second and last "s and fix the month bit

Answer (score 1):

Change your JavaScript as

```
window.location="http://test.rgniyd.com/test1/?q=node/36/&dept=" + dept + "&bath=" + bat + "&month=" + month + "&year=" + year + "&semester=" + sem;
```

Because you have misplaced double quotes `"`

Comment: How to send these data in POST Method?

Comment: @BalaKrishnan Please mark it as answer, helpful to close the issue

Comment: @BalaKrishnan Using window.location.href it's not possible to send a POST request.

Comment: @BalaKrishnan may be it could be helpful you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2367979/pass-post-data-with-window-location-href

Answer (score 0):

You have messed up (*a bit*) the string concatenation..

```
window.location="http://test.rgniyd.com/test1/?q=node/36/&dept="+ dept +"&bath="+  
bat +"&month="+month+"&year="+year+"&semester="+sem;
```

Comment: Not possible with `window.location`. You will have to create a form, fill it and submit it..