# Calling Servlet from JavaScript

Tags: java, javascript, jsp, servlets

I intend to call a function in JavaScript which then calls a Servlet after an `<input type="image">` is clicked.

**JSP:**

```
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function callServlet() {
            document.location.href="test-servlet.jsp";
        }
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <form action="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
    ...
    <input type="image" name="submit"
        src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/webstatic/en_US/btn/btn_buynow_pp_142x27.png"
        onclick="callServlet()" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online!">
    </form>
</body>
```

**Servlet (`test-servlet.jsp`):**

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    response.setContentType("text/html");

    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

    out.println("<h1>TestServlet called successfully!</h1>");
}
```

**Context Root:**
`http://localhost:8080/mysite/test-servlet.jsp`
However, nothing happens when I click the image button. I am new to JavaScript.

Comment: you can use jquery instead of using javascript. Is there any specific requirement that bounds you to use javascript only?

Comment: @Rockstar How would jQuery help with the question :)? http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/45176/when-is-use-jquery-not-a-valid-answer-to-a-javascript-question

Comment: What are your intentions? The form is submitting on PayPal and you are trying to modify location when submit is clicked (**race condition**). Also changing the location would generate GET request, but your servlet is handling POST... so there are multiple issues with the code you presented.

Comment: so why not @PavelHoral ?. I think the OP wants to make a servlet call on click.

Comment: I'm sorry if i have taken it in a wrong way. Might be my poor understanding of the intention of the OP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code

```
<a href="#" onclick="callServlet()"><img
    src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/webstatic/en_US/btn/btn_buynow_pp_142x27.png"
    alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online!"></a>
```

EDIT:

Finally we discovered that a servlet should be mapped  without extension and `doGet` method is used to get the request from javascript.

Comment: I guess he is trying to access the url `test-servlet` not the one in the action attribute

Comment: @SanKrish He wants an image button to go to a jsp page

Comment: but his title suggests _Calling Servlet from JavaScript_ :(

Comment: @SanKrish Read below, *nothing happens when I click the image button*.

Comment: @ohtph servlet or jsp ? it should be as `test-servlet` alone . try my answer if you need to be done using javascript

Comment: This is an image button that call a javascript function on click event. When it's executed you will be redirected to jsp page

Comment: Sorry for causing confusion, my servlet is just mapped as `test-servlet.jsp`, it is not actually a jsp.

Comment: @ohtph poor mapping . dont try with those kinds of mapping it causes confusion. as jsp is a standard , you can go for some other patterns like .htm , .do like that

Comment: @RomanC the next line _I am new to JavaScript._ and even it wont accept the post request as he's trying to pass it in the post

Comment: You should map a servlet without extension and use `doGet` method.

Comment: @RomanC, what I did was remove doPost(), put a sysout and a response.sendRedirect() to PayPal Sandbox in the TestServlet doGet(). I also mapped it as `testservlet` without extension. If you can post your comment as an answer, I will mark it accepted. Thanks. :)

Comment: @SanKrish, thank you also for your comment, it was also a clue so I upvoted it. I will also upvote your answer. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

I Could see multiple errors in your jsp .

First of all ,

```
<form action="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
```

And also use the `img` tag with `button` as Roman says

the url in the `action` is called , when your form is being submitted

so try replacing it with ,

```
<form action="./test-servlet" method="post">
```

and using your JavaScript now,

You cant use `window.location.href` to make a `POST` request . check [pass post data with window.location.href](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2367979/pass-post-data-with-window-location-href)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function callServlet() {
        document.forms[0].submit;
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Hi, the `https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr` redirects to the PayPal Sandbox site which is required. The reason I want to call another test-servlet is for it to set a boolean `isPaypalButtonClicked`. Is that possible?

Comment: so you want it to stay on the same page ?if so use ajax to do the work for you

Comment: Sadly, we are not allowed to touch AJAX as of yet. jQuery and JS is allowed (but minimal).

Comment: so you can call the servlet , set the values to the request and re-direct back to the jsp.