# Request body missing when trying to reach an endpoint with window.location.href

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, spring-mvc

Hello guys i having an error status 404 basically i am trying to go into another endpoint but receving error code:

```
There was an unexpected error (type=Bad Request, status=400).
Required request body content is missing: org.springframework.web.method.HandlerMethod$HandlerMethodParameter@2c553a08

$.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            url: 'guest/search',

            data: JSON.stringify(formData),
            contentType: 'application/json',
            success: function(dataRecieved){
                var dataRecieved= $.trim(dataRecieved);
                //console.log(dataRecieved);
                if(dataRecieved === 'true'){
                    $("#statusPlaceholder").html("Great rooms are available");
                    window.location.href="/guestReservation";
                }else{
                    $("#statusPlaceholder").html("Sorry. Rooms are not available. Please try again").show().fadeOut(3000).css("color","red");
                }
            }

        });
```

Spring mapping:

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/guestReservation", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String createGuest(@RequestBody Guest guest){
        // return new ResponseEntity<>(guestservice.create(gst), HttpStatus.OK);
        return "guestReservation";
    }
```

My question is how do i add a request body in window.location.href

Comment: You need to POST to `/guestReservation` rather than GET (which location.href does).  Edit: Which contradicts your Spring mapping...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [HTTP GET with request body](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/978061/http-get-with-request-body)

Comment: More likely duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2367979/pass-post-data-with-window-location-href   Summary: Using window.location.href it's not possible to send a POST request.

Comment: @freedomn-m so how do i solve the problem

Comment: @freedomn-m im not sending a post a request I'm trying to go to another page. Please could u assist

Comment: You could change your Spring mapping to accept the parameters on the url query string (ie just remove @RequestBody)

Comment: @freedomn-m I'm going to a page that needs to make a reservation so i retrieve the data from the url mapping /guestReservation thats why i added the RequestBody.

Comment: "retrieve the data from the url" "RequestBody" - these are not the same thing.  `location.href="/guestReservation?reservationId=x&guestName=y"` would be passing it on the url.

Comment: @freedomn-m thanks for the help i actually solved. I really appreciate your  patience and comments.