# DateTime difference php

Tags: javascript, php

We are using a form to submit the data and getting the response from our API the code below works fine -

```
if (0 == strlen($_POST['from_location'])) {
    $_response[] = 'Enter from location';
}
if (0 == strlen($_POST['to_location'])) {
    $_response[] = 'Enter to location';
}

try {
        $_fromDate=DateTime::createFromFormat('m/d/Y',$_POST['from_date']);
        $_toDate =  DateTime::createFromFormat('m/d/Y', $_POST['to_date']); 
        $_interval = $_fromDate->diff($_toDate); //Line 21 where error comes
        $_noOfDays = $_interval->format('%d');
}catch(Exception $e){
    $_response[] = $e->getMessage();
}
```

Corresponding JS code used in our HTML submit page is -

```
function testAjaxCall(formobj) {
                $.post(
                    formobj.action,
                    $(formobj).serialize(),
                    function (response, status, jqXhr) {
                        alert(response);
                    },
                    'html'
                );
            }
```

The above code works fine and gives us the response from API.

However, when we try to change the JS code to -

```
function testAjaxCall(formobj) {
                $.post(
                    formobj.action,
                    $(formobj).serialize(),
                    function (response, status, jqXhr) {
                        //alert(response);
                        location.href = 'hotel_search.php';
                    },
                    'html'
                );
            }
```

We get the following Notices and a fatal error the notices are removed by using isset for our input fields. The dates need to be send back in Y/m/d format as thats how we receive the response. I have already gone through the Stackoverflow and googled it as well however, none of the solutions are working for us.

> Notice: Undefined index: from_location in
>   /home/developeriq/public_html/doylesweb/hotel_search.php on line 11
>
> Notice: Undefined index: to_location in
>   /home/developeriq/public_html/doylesweb/hotel_search.php on line 14
>
> Notice: Undefined index: from_date in
>   /home/developeriq/public_html/doylesweb/hotel_search.php on line 19
>
> Notice: Undefined index: to_date in
>   /home/developeriq/public_html/doylesweb/hotel_search.php on line 20
>
> Fatal error: Call to a member function diff() on a non-object in
>   /home/developeriq/public_html/doylesweb/hotel_search.php on line 21

Can anyone please help and see what we are doing wrong.

Thanks

Comment: You're building the $_response array if $_POST values aren't set, but you're still trying to use values from $_POST in calls to DateTime::createFromFormat() regardless

Comment: what is `formobj` here?

Comment: The problem is not in your date difference implementation - it's that you can't send POST variables with window.location.href.  Try submitting a form, as these answers suggest: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2367979/pass-post-data-with-window-location-href.

Comment: Thanks I will go through the same

Comment: Its solved in my code if added the following condition to deal with the format - if ($_toDate instanceof DateTime && $_fromDate instanceof DateTime) {
   $_interval = $_fromDate->diff($_toDate);
   $_noOfDays = $_interval->format('%d');
  }