# Ajax Follow Java Serverlet Redirect

Tags: java, jquery, json, ajax, java-server

I'm making a certain ajax request to a java serverlet in the following manner :

```
var request = $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: MY_SERVERLET_URL,
    data: MY_DATA,
    dataType: 'json',
});

request.done(function(msg) {
    if (msg.hasOwnProperty("status")) {
        var jsonObject = msg["status"].toString();
        if (jsonObject == "success") {
            // GET RELEVANT URL AND DATA FROM JSON OBJECT AND REDIRECT TO
            // THE URL WITH DATA ATTACHED FROM JAVASCRIPT
        }
        else {
            // ERROR
        }
    }
    else {
       // ERROR
    }
});

request.fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus) {
    alert("Error : " + textStatus);
});
```

**What I have Done**

Currently the Java serverlet completes its work and returns a certain `URL` and a set of data inside a JSON Object to the ajax request, where the ajax request in turn will parse that data and make a certain POST request to the specified url.

**What I Want To Do**

I want to do this **without returning the data to the client side**, meaning to make the request from the Java serverlet directly to the the `url` but the ajax request from the client side should also **follow that request**. (The user should be redirected to the specified URL)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [pass post data with window.location.href](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2367979/pass-post-data-with-window-location-href).

Comment: @paul.F-G No, in my case i want to send the POST request from Java itself.

Comment: So you want to get additional data in your servlet from a POST request and then send a redirect or forward to the client with this data? What servlet container are you using?

Comment: A basic web container, but its running independently. Meaning the JS (client side) is hosted in a different server and the Java Serverlet hosted in another server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've understand that you want to make an internal POST request in your servlet and forward or redirect the client according to what you've received.

[image: activity]

### Client side

A simple form could be enough. Submit with XHR or not.

**HTML**

```
<form action="/yourServlet" method="POST">
    <input type="hidden" name="data" value="value" />
</form>
```

### Server side

**Encode parameters to queryString**

```
public String getEncodedQueryString(Map<String, String> parameters) {
    StringBuilder queryStringBuilder = new StringBuilder("?");
    parameters.entrySet().stream().forEach(e -> {
        queryStringBuilder.append(e.getKey());
        queryStringBuilder.append("=");
        try {
            queryStringBuilder.append(
                URLEncoder.encode(e.getValue() == null ? "" : e.getValue().toString(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8.name())
            );
        }
        catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e1) {
            queryStringBuilder.append("");
        }
        queryStringBuilder.append("&");
    });
    return queryStringBuilder.toString().substring(0, queryStringBuilder.toString().length()-1);
}
```

**Post your data to some URL inside your servlet**

(maybe the URL is one of your parameters as well from the POST?)

```
URLConnection connection = new URL(url).openConnection();
connection.setDoOutput(true); // POST
connection.setRequestProperty("Accept-Charset", "UTF-8");
connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8");
try (OutputStream output = connection.getOutputStream()) {
    output.write(getEncodedQueryString(request.getParameterMap()).getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
}
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
String inputLine;
while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) { sb.append(inputLine); }
in.close();
```

**Write your data**

```
request.setAttribute("param", sb.toString());
/*
    return ResponseBody<> or String or whatever according
    to your servlet container like you're doing usually
*/
```

Hope this helps.