# Show a particular DIV from a previously viewed page

Tags: html, forms

I'm not sure if this is possible (I'm not a coder!) but here goes anyway...

The DIV class for the product name on the following page is "productTitle"
https://www.ultimadisplays.co.uk/Alcohol_Hand_Sanitiser_Gel/?categoryId=2147499177&tab=0&subTab=1

I won't bore you with why but the website is very old and limited however we can put a button on each product page which can link to a form. This form is on a completely separate hosted platform.
Is it therefore possible to take the product name over to the new page with the form on it using the DIV class so that when the form is submitted we will know what product they are interested in rather than they have to write it into the form manually?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can send whatever data you want between different sites or platforms by sending it in GET or POST request either by refreshing page directly or by using AJAX.

I don't think it's a good option just for a form. But you have this possibility nevertheless.

Comment: Thank you for this, much appreciated! I don't suppose you have an example of these by any chance? Sorry, my coding experience is limited!

Comment: It's not possible to write a ready solution, your task is more complex than that. If my response was usefull, you can rate up this answer for me. Thank you

Comment: If you want, you can read about GET and POST http requests and how to perform them depending on the framework/language you're using. For example, in Javascript on the front-end if you're planning to use AJAX functionality you have 3 options:
-xmlHttpRequest
-jQuery.ajax()
-fetch()
If you're not planning to use AJAX, you can read this topic
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2367979/pass-post-data-with-window-location-href
You make the form here and you send it to another web resource