# Pass data without the use of window.location

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code which works fine but shows the appended query string:

```
 var url = '@Url.Action("RawDataPageTable", "Chlor", new { id = Model.Senid })';
 url = url +  '?Voting=' + isChecked;

 window.location = url;
```

With how I am sending the parameter info, it is shown on the browser.

I tried to do the following so no query string is not visible in place of window.location = url but it did nothing:

```
 $.redirect(url,
 {
     Voting: isChecked
 });
```

Is there any other way to pass data in such a way that it is not visible in the URL?  Note that I am using jQuery.

Anyway to do this in a $.post in jquery so we can pass the data?

Comment: `$.post` will make an ajax request: https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/

Comment: Does this answer your question? [pass post data with window.location.href](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2367979/pass-post-data-with-window-location-href)

Comment: You could also encode your querystring. Sending the unencoded data to the server, which will redirect you to an url with the encoded string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is yes. And the way to do it is to use a FORM. In particular, you should learn about the FORM method (learn about [REST][1] commands).

It sounds like you should be using POST.

[1]: [https://www.restapitutorial.com/lessons/httpmethods.html#:~:text=The%20primary%20or%20most%2Dcommonly,or%20CRUD](https://www.restapitutorial.com/lessons/httpmethods.html#:%7E:text=The%20primary%20or%20most%2Dcommonly,or%20CRUD))%20operations%2C%20respectively.

Answer (score 0):

I would add a form to your page, with method="post", put all your variables as hidden inputs, then submit the form.