# Json Cannot be Parsed

Tags: php, laravel, postman, guzzle

I am trying to post an object using Guzzle laravel which I pass it using form submit from my view but when I do it says INVALID FORMAT Json Cannot Be Parsed

My View

```
            <form method="POST" action="comparePrices">
                @csrf
                <input type="text" name="datas" id="textsss"/>
                <input type="submit" value="save"/>
            </form>
```

But when I post it via postman it works fine

My Controller

```
        public function comparePrices(Request $request)
    {
        $token = DB::table('a_p_is_tokens')->select('*')->limit(1)->orderBy('id', 'desc')->get()->pluck('token')[0];
        $client = new Client();

        try {
            $res = $client->post('https://test.api.amadeus.com/v1/shopping/flight-offers/pricing', [

                'headers' => [
                    'Content-Type' => 'application/json', 'Accept' => 'application/json', 'Authorization' => 'Bearer ' . $token,
                ],
                'form_params' => [
                    "data"=>[
                        "type" => "flight-offers-pricing",
                        "flightOffers" => $request->datas,
                    ],
                // 'body'    => array('data'=>$items),
            ]);

            $res = json_decode($res->getBody()->getContents(), true);
            $response = $res->getResponse();

            print_r(json_decode($response->getBody(), true));
            // return view('agents.agentsTickets');
        } catch (RequestException $e) {
            $response = $e->getResponse();
            $result =  json_decode($response->getBody()->getContents());
            return response()->json(['data' => $result]);
            // return [json_decode($request->datas)];

        }
        dd([$items]);
        return view('agents.agentsTickets');
    }
```

Error Code

```
{
  "data": {
    "errors": [
      {
        "code": 477,
        "title": "INVALID FORMAT",
        "detail": "JSON cannot be parsed",
        "status": 400
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Why would you pass data of that length as a URL parameter to begin with? You're probably in danger of hitting the limit of URL size that common clients allow for. (And you did not even apply proper URL encoding.)

Comment: Also I'm wondering, whether that error message is actually supposed to mean that the JSON was _invalid_ - or whether it might just be telling you, that what data you are sending is _structured_ wrong.

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Where are you stuck? Have you checked whether Postman does anything different than Guzzle?

Comment: ....for example: why does your request in Postman start with a `data` key, while your Guzzle request does not?

Comment: Thank you, everyone, for mentioning my mistake Now I send data via form but still gets the same error

Comment: And what have you tried to resolve that problem? Why not debug the request that is sent? As far as I see, you still don't send everything wrapped in a `data` element

Comment: Thanks, I edited the question. even with this still same problem

Comment: And what have you tried to resolve the problem? Where are your debugging attempts?

Answer (score 0):

Your js code does **http GET** not **http POST**

```
window.location='postings/'+items;
```

If it should be possible to add "items" into url abd perform **http GET** then you could try to do the same in Postman - use GET not POST and modify the url, not the body.

If you intend to do in js the same as in Postman then I suggest to see answers from [pass post data with window.location.href](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2367979/pass-post-data-with-window-location-href) and modify your js code. Or try https://reqbin.com/req/javascript/uzf79ewc/javascript-post-request-example

Comment: As you said I did everything but still not working I try it on https://reqbin.com/req/javascript/uzf79ewc/javascript-post-request-example  it works fine with my data but in laravel, it doess not.

Comment: By the way https://reqbin.com/req/javascript/uzf79ewc/javascript-post-request-example is very useful up vote for the link